# Query params on detail view return a list instead of json nested serializers Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, output

I'm rather new to Django Rest Framework and I'm having a problem I don't quite understand.

If I setup a APIView to return all the objects in a particular model I get an array of data as expected

```
class ProcedureListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        procedures = AutomationProcedure.objects.all()
        serializer = AutomationProcedureSerializer(procedures, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My api call to this endpoint looks like

```
$ http --json GET http://localhost:8000/api/procedures/
```

And the response 
        [
           {
             ...
             ...
            }
        ]

But if I write a detail view that takes query parameters the single object still returns as a list

```
class ProcedureDetail(generics.ListAPIView):

 def get_queryset(self):

    queryset = AutomationProcedure.objects.all()
    display_name = self.request.query_params.get('display_name', None)
    if display_name is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(display_name=display_name)
    return queryset
```

And then if I make an API call in this manner:

```
$ http --json GET http://localhost:8000/api/procedures/ display_name="jenkins"
```

The response still comes back as a list.

```
[
  {
     ...
     ...
   }
]
```

Now I know that Detailview is inheiriting from ListAPIView which it would make sense that it would come back as a List. But what am I supposed to do here? Override the serializer method to represent it as json or something? Thanks for your help in advance this has been a tough one

The desired output would be something like

{
 ... 
 ... # Various nested objects

}

The data comes out exactly the way I want with the exception of the the surrounding [] for the detail view. If I rewrite the method and do something like

```
return Response(serializer.data[0])
```

This works out perfectly. But seems kind of hacky

Here are my serializers

```
class AutomationTemplateParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AutomationTemplateParameter
        fields = ['sys_automation_template_parameter_id', 'sys_automation_template_id', 'parameter_name',
              'parameter_value', 'default_value', 'description', 'display_name']


class AutomationTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    template_parameters = AutomationTemplateParameterSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AutomationTemplate
        fields = ['sys_automation_template_id', 'template_name', 'template_code',
              'template_code', 'display_name', 'description', 'template_parameters']


class AutomationProcedureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    procedure_template = AutomationTemplateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
    model = AutomationProcedure
    fields = ['sys_automation_procedure_id', 'sys_application_service_id', 'procedure_code', 'description', 'display_name', 'command_line_args',
              'procedure_template']
    lookup_field = 'display_name'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        procedures = super(AutomationProcedureSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return {'procedures': procedures}
```

EDIT:

I've updated the method to use a RetrieveApiView generics. I don't seem to be getting the attribute errors I was before but now the regex doesn't seem to be working

```
class ProcedureDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = AutomationProcedure
    serializer_class = AutomationProcedureSerializer
    lookup_field = ('display_name')
```

urls

```
url(r'^(?P<display_name>[a-zA-Z]+(?i))$', views.ProcedureDetail.as_view()),
```

api response

```
http --json GET http://localhost:8000/api/procedures/ display_name="Jenkins"


 Not Found: /api/procedures/
[24/Jul/2018 15:37:59] "GET /api/procedures/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2640
```

Comment: If you want a single instance, you should inherit from [RetrieveAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) rather than ListAPIView.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So I've read that and makes total sense to me, but then a bunch of my serializer fields start pulling AttributeErrors.

Comment: What errors? Show them (in the question).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Adding them now, need to rewrite the method

Comment: The URL you are requesting makes no sense; you need `http://localhost:8000/api/procedures/Jenkins`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My root level url conf has a route for /api/procedures/

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was trying to add the regex for the lookup field

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You don't request a regex, you request a URL, which is as I showed above.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the lookup field as a query parameter.. So for example if I don't specify a parameter

AssertionError: Expected view ProcedureDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "display_name". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: I see the problem. My regex is fine. It's the query that was wrong. You are correct @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please add your answer so I can accept it as the correct one. RetrieveAPIView was the answer